# Show that $(\textbf{S}^*\textbf{B})(u,v)=\textbf{B}(\textbf{S}(u,v))\cdot \textbf{N}(u,v) \ du \wedge dv$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces, differential-forms

> Let $\textbf{S}(u,v):[0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a singular $2$-cube which is smooth. Note that $0 \leq u,v \leq 1$.
>
> Let $B(\textbf{r})=B_x \ dy \wedge dz + B_y \ dz \wedge dx + B_z \ dx \wedge dy$ be a $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> Show that $(\textbf{S}^*\textbf{B})(u,v)=\textbf{B}(\textbf{S}(u,v))\cdot \textbf{N}(u,v) \ du \wedge dv$,
>
> where $\textbf{B}=(B_x, B_y, B_z)$ and $\displaystyle \textbf{N}=\frac{\partial \textbf{S}}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \textbf{S}}{\partial v}$
>
> Please note that my (rough) definition of a pullback is $(F^*\beta)(x;u_1,\dots,u_n)=\beta(F(x); F'(x)u_1,\dots,F'(x)u_n)$.

$\begin{align}(\textbf{S}^*\textbf{B})(u,v) &= (\textbf{B} \circ \textbf{S})(u,v) \\
&= \textbf{B}(\textbf{S}(u,v)) \\
&= (B_x \ dy \wedge dz + B_y \ dz \wedge dx + B_z \ dx \wedge dy ) (\textbf{S}(u,v)) \\
&= (B_x \ dy \wedge dz)(\textbf{S}(u,v)) + (B_y \ dz \wedge dx)(\textbf{S}(u,v)) + (B_z \ dx \wedge dy) (\textbf{S}(u,v)) \\
&= B_x(\textbf{S}(u,v)) ( dy \wedge dz)(\textbf{S}(u,v)) + B_y(\textbf{S}(u,v)) ( dz \wedge dx)(\textbf{S}(u,v)) + B_z(\textbf{S}(u,v)) ( dx \wedge dy) (\textbf{S}(u,v)) \\
&= ...
\end{align}$

Now just looking at the first term, I believe others with follow almost identically, I get that

$$\begin{align}B_x(\textbf{S}(u,v)) ( dy \wedge dz)(\textbf{S} (u,v)) &= B_x(\textbf{S}(u,v)) \left[ dy(\textbf{S} (u,v)) dz - dz(\textbf{S} (u,v)) dy)\right] \\
&= B_x(\textbf{S}(u,v)) \left[ dS_2 dz - dS_3 dy)\right] \\
&= B_x(\textbf{S}(u,v)) \left[\left( \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial v}dv \right) dz - \left( \frac{\partial S_3}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial S_3}{\partial v}dv \right) dy\right] \\
&= B_x(\textbf{S}(u,v)) \left[\left( \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial v}dv \right) \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}dv\right) 
- \left( \frac{\partial S_3}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial S_3}{\partial v}dv \right) \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv\right)\right] \\
\end{align}$$

Iam unsure whether this last equality is correct and how to proceed from here. I do not understand where the $du \wedge dv$ has gone or where it could come from.

Comment: If your first two lines were correct, you'd have $(S^{*}B)(u, v) = B(S(u, v))$, but you're supposed to have $(S^{*}B)(u, v) = B(S(u, v)) \cdot N(u, v) du \wedge dv$. If we believe the problem is correct (and I do), then your first two lines must be incorrect. I suggest that you try evaluating $(S^{*}B)(u, v)$, which is a 2-form, on a pair of vectors. Why not try $(S^{*}B)(u, v)(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial}{\partial v})$, and see whether you get the same thing as the right hand side evaluated on this pair of vectors?

Comment: I have the definition $(F^*\beta)(x;u_1,\dots,u_n)=\beta(F(x); F'(x)u_1,\dots,F'(x)u_n)$, but I thought $(u,v)$ corresponds to the $x$ not the vector to which either side applied

Comment: You're correct...but notice that the remaining arguments to $\beta(F(x); \ldots$ are not the same as the remaining arguments to $F^{*}\beta(x; \ldots)$, which would be necessary for them to be equal as functions. (To say $f = g$ is to say that $f$ and $g$ have the same domain and codomain, and that for every $s$ in the domain, $f(s) = g(s)$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\omega=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ we have $B=i(\mathbf{B})\omega$. The simplest way to verify that $\mathbf{S}^*(B)=\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{N}du\wedge dv$ is to apply both of sides to the basis vectors $\partial_u, \partial_v$. We have $$\mathbf{S}^*(B)(\partial_u, \partial_v)=B(\mathbf{S}_u, \mathbf{S}_v)$$
$$=i(\mathbf{B})\omega(\mathbf{S}_u, \mathbf{S}_v)=\omega(\mathbf{B}, \mathbf{S}_u, \mathbf{S}_v)$$
$$=\det(\mathbf{B},\mathbf{S}_u, \mathbf{S}_v)=\mathbf{B}\cdot(\mathbf{S}_u\times\mathbf{S}_v)$$
$$=\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{N}$$

See [Triple product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) for reference.

Comment: Sorry I really understand your steps. Could they be explained in further detail please?

Comment: My steps are only unwinding of definitions. Which step don't you understand? If you don't know what is an interior product you may refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product but it is really simple a definition.

Comment: Interior product isnt the problem. Ill look again later.

Comment: The first = is only applying the definition of pull back. The second is a plug in; The third is the definition of interior product; The forth is the definition of differential forms; the fifth is the definition of triple product, the last is a plug in.

Comment: I think it might be to do with that my course is slightly on the basic side. Can you understand what is wrong with my line of thinking, which largely uses stuff given in my notes?

Comment: For example, $S^*(dy\wedge dz)$ should be $d(y∘S)\wedge d(y∘S)$

Comment: Possibly its a similiar problem to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083354/understanding-the-definition-of-a-pullback-of-a-differential-k-form-and-applyi

Comment: Have I not done $d(y∘S)\wedge d(y∘S)$ in (second equality of last calculation) $B_x(\textbf{S}(u,v)) \left[ dS_2 dz - dS_3 dy)\right]$?

Comment: oh then you'll proceed to expand and use the fact $du\wedge du=0$ and $du\wedge dv=-dv\wedge du$.

Comment: Sorry im not quite sure what you mean by that. Which bit of $B_x(\textbf{S}(u,v)) \left[\left( \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial v}dv \right) dz - \left( \frac{\partial S_3}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial S_3}{\partial v}dv \right) dy\right]$ do you think is wrong (the next equality)?

Comment: oh I didn't see anything wrong yet since I didn't examine carefully, ignore that comments and proceed to expand.